# Postgresql crashes when query run

Tags: postgresql, postgis

When I run the following query I get `FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode`. I can select the geometry, and it works fine on a cube, but this is a complex closed polyhedral surface geometry, could this be a size issue, are there any settings I should change to allow computationally demanding queries?

Using windows 10, PostgreSQL 10 + Postgis

```
CREATE TABLE t35_39 AS
SELECT geom AS geom, ST_Volume(ST_MAKESOLID(geom)) AS Volume FROM public.c35_39
```

logs

```
2019-03-22 19:54:57.894 +03 [37392] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: select st_makesolid(geom) from public.c35_39
2019-03-22 19:54:57.894 +03 [37392] HINT:  See C include file "ntstatus.h" for a description of the hexadecimal value.
2019-03-22 19:54:57.894 +03 [37392] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2019-03-22 19:54:57.896 +03 [34452] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2019-03-22 19:54:57.896 +03 [34452] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2019-03-22 19:54:57.896 +03 [34452] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2019-03-22 19:54:57.914 +03 [37392] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2019-03-22 19:54:57.961 +03 [26764] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-03-22 19:30:21 +03
2019-03-22 19:54:58.990 +03 [15400] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2019-03-22 19:54:59.051 +03 [32032] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2019-03-22 19:55:00.880 +03 [26764] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2019-03-22 19:55:00.897 +03 [26764] LOG:  redo starts at 46/E0EA5580
2019-03-22 19:55:00.897 +03 [26764] LOG:  invalid record length at 46/E0EA55B8: wanted 24, got 0
2019-03-22 19:55:00.897 +03 [26764] LOG:  redo done at 46/E0EA5580
2019-03-22 19:55:00.987 +03 [37392] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2019-03-22 19:55:51.532 +03 [37392] LOG:  server process (PID 18092) was terminated by exception 0xC0000005
2019-03-22 19:55:51.532 +03 [37392] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: select st_makesolid(geom) from public.c35_39
2019-03-22 19:55:51.532 +03 [37392] HINT:  See C include file "ntstatus.h" for a description of the hexadecimal value.
2019-03-22 19:55:51.532 +03 [37392] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2019-03-22 19:55:51.533 +03 [1564] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2019-03-22 19:55:51.533 +03 [1564] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2019-03-22 19:55:51.533 +03 [1564] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2019-03-22 19:55:51.534 +03 [4080] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2019-03-22 19:55:51.534 +03 [4080] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2019-03-22 19:55:51.534 +03 [4080] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2019-03-22 19:55:51.552 +03 [37392] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2019-03-22 19:55:51.600 +03 [44368] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-03-22 19:55:00 +03
2019-03-22 19:55:54.139 +03 [15980] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2019-03-22 19:55:54.197 +03 [41864] FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2019-03-22 19:55:54.580 +03 [44368] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2019-03-22 19:55:54.597 +03 [44368] LOG:  redo starts at 46/E0EA5628
2019-03-22 19:55:54.597 +03 [44368] LOG:  invalid record length at 46/E0EA5660: wanted 24, got 0
2019-03-22 19:55:54.597 +03 [44368] LOG:  redo done at 46/E0EA5628
2019-03-22 19:55:54.678 +03 [37392] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Comment: What do the PostgreSQL logs say?

Comment: logs added to the question

Comment: Does this happen on Postgres 11? Is it a known bug in Postgres 10 and/or PostGIS?

Comment: no idea, seems a problem with st_makesolid, I'm applying it to a converted ply which is fairly complex, does postgis struggle with high face counts for tins/polyhedrals?

Comment: You should [get a stack trace](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Generating_a_stack_trace_of_a_PostgreSQL_backend) from that crash and report it as PostGIS bug, ideally together with code to reproduce the problem.